# Issues with Regex matcher on APEX

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I'm looking to create a regex that will grab all of the lines of text which comply with the following structure:

- Group1: 2-3 chars of upper case letters
- Group2: A datetime of day month and year with flexible separators
- Group3: Any block of text up to an end a line

Any blank spaces between the groups would be ignored. Currently the regex I have built is `(?m)([A-Z]{2,3})[\s]+([0-9]+[-\/\.][0-9][0-9][-\/\.][0-9]+)[\s:,-]+([^\n]+)$` and it works on a few regex testing sites that I have gone to with this sample text:

```
#Rubbish
AA 22/05/2017: First block of text. \n
BB 15/05/2017: Second block of text. \n
AA 01/05/2017: Third block  of text \n\n
```

Rubbish block

To be precise I've tried on https://regex101.com/ and there if I enable the global flag, all of the rows get detected, without it only the first, but I at least get a match. But when I take it into Apex I end up with this code

```
string message = '#Rubbish \n' + 
'AA 22/05/2017: First block of text. \n' +
'BB 15/05/2017: Second block of text. \n' +
'AA 01/05/2017: Third block  of text \n\n' +
'Rubbish block';

System.debug(message);

// Preparing regex
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile('(?m)([A-Z]{2,3})[\s]+([0-9]+[-\/\.][0-9][0-9][-\/\.][0-9]+)[\s:,-]+([^\n]+)$');
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(message);

if(regexMatcher.matches() == true) {
    System.debug(regexMatcher);
}
else {
    System.debug('no');
}
```

And initially I get compilation errors. I play a bit with the regex string, escaping the \ by adding an additional one, but I'm still unable to get any actual matches even when I don't get compilation errors anymore.

Could anybody have a look and tell me what is wrong? I'm convinced it's a dumb oversight, but I'm still not managing to see the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two issues here: one is escaping the regex correctly, and one is the semantics of checking for a match. The following code works:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile('(?m)([A-Z]{2,3})[\\s]+([0-9]+[\\-/.][0-9][0-9][\\-/.][0-9]+)[\\s:,-]+([^\\n]+)$');
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(message);

while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    System.debug(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

> 09:43:06:004 USER_DEBUG [14]|DEBUG|AA 22/05/2017: First block of text.

> 09:43:06:004 USER_DEBUG [14]|DEBUG|BB 15/05/2017: Second block of text.

> 09:43:06:004 USER_DEBUG [14]|DEBUG|AA 01/05/2017: Third block  of text

Note that [`Matcher.matches()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods.htm#apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods) returns `true` for a whole-region (whole-string, in this case) match, which we don't have. `find()` returns `true` when we're able to match, which we are here.

Additionally, you must escape all backslashes in an Apex string, and there's no need to escape a forward slash or period in a regex character class.

Comment: (Thanks, @DerekF; I re-pasted my code and screwed up the formatting)

Comment: You can remove `==true` and just use `while (regexMatcher.find())`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, seemed like in my playing around I did get to the point where I was escaping properly, but didn't catch the difference of use between Matcher and Find. Thanks a lot.